# Position fixed not working for google maps

Tags: html, css

I have included Google Maps within my page and I would like it to be fixed as I have a long list to the left of the map. However I have added `position: fixed;` and when I scroll the map stops and it just shows a white area under the map:

[image]

Here is my CSS for the list to the left and the map on the right:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 480px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "list map";
  }

.list {
    grid-area: list;
    height: 100vh;
}

#map { 
    grid-area: map;
    position: fixed;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
   <form id="form1" runat="server">

   <div class="grid-container">

   <div class="list">
   <div class="navigation-bar"></div>

   <div class="tiles"></div>
   </div>

   <div id="map"></div>

  </div>
 </form>
</body>
```

I have tried several different options from Stack Overflow to try and fix it however none of them have worked so any help on how to stop this would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include your HTML code as well, it helps when we know how you have structured your code

Comment: I have now added my HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#map { 
    grid-area: map;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

should do the trick

Also check out this for a detailed explanation
https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46

Comment: I have tried your code and also looked into the link however none of this is working for me. Thank you for your help anyway.